# Git - Reverting a merged pull request

Tags: git, github

I merged in a couple of pull requests on our master today, but forgot to get the second pull request rebased. I came across the revert option whilst Googling how to undo a merge, so gave this a go and sure enough it gave me a new pull request with the reverts in and so I merged in.

When reviewing the commit history, I see this didn't give me back a linear commit history, I think I understand why.

But all I need to do is get the master back to where it was on the last good rebased pull request, which as per the screen shot below would be the #87 pull request.

[image]

I'm working in a very small team, and the guys are happy to leave as just one of those things, but I'd rather fix this now.

I'm thinking I just need to pull the latest changes on master locally, reset HEAD back 4 iterations and do a force push and then get the second pull request re-issued after being rebased of course.

Does this sound sensible? The last thing I want to do is nuke our branch somehow.
Thanks

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by keeping a linear history? It sounds like you're just making more work for no gain.

Comment: It's more a case that the commits related to the second merge are not detailed just below it as me and my team are used to seeing. However - I have just been reading a bit more on how the auto merge works when hitting the green merge button on GitHub, without fast-forward, and so end up with these merge messages in the commit history. I see there are ways at command line to use the fast forward option when merging pull requests onto a master - I guess it's just down to preferences of teams how they want there commit history to appear?